# How to join multiple tables in KUSTO and select values as columns?

Tags: azure-application-insights, kql

I've the following data which comes from multiple datasources (multiple application insight instances). Just for explanation, i've reduced this to datatables.

```
let table1 = datatable(companyCode:string, status:string, environment:string) 
[
    "company1", "Healthy", "DEV",
    "company2", "Healthy", "DEV", 
    "company3", "Healthy", "DEV",
];
let table2 = datatable(companyCode:string, status:string, environment:string) 
[
    "company1", "Healthy", "TEST",
    "company2", "Healthy", "TEST", 
    "company4", "Healthy", "TEST",
];
let table3 = datatable(companyCode:string, status:string, environment:string) 
[
    "company1", "Healthy", "UAT",
    "company2", "Healthy", "UAT", 
    "company4", "Healthy", "UAT",
    "company5", "Healthy", "UAT",
];
```

Now I want to select all the values to get the following result table:

| companyCode | DEV | TEST | UAT |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| company1 | Healthy | Healthy | Healthy |
| company2 | Healthy | Healthy | Healthy |
| company3 | Healthy |  |  |
| company4 |  | Healthy | Healthy |
| company5 |  |  | Healthy |

I've tried something like this with no luck, because i got one row per table for each company.

```
table1
| extend DEV = status
| union withsource=SourceTable kind=outer 
   ( table2 | extend TEST = status),
   ( table3 | extend UAT = status)
| project companyCode, DEV, TEST, UAT
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're very nearly there :)  You could do it with joins instead of union.

Here's how I'd approach it.

```
let table1 = datatable(companyCode:string, status:string, environment:string) 
[
    "company1", "Healthy", "DEV",
    "company2", "Healthy", "DEV", 
    "company3", "Healthy", "DEV",
];
let table2 = datatable(companyCode:string, status:string, environment:string) 
[
    "company1", "Healthy", "TEST",
    "company2", "Healthy", "TEST", 
    "company4", "Healthy", "TEST",
];
let table3 = datatable(companyCode:string, status:string, environment:string) 
[
    "company1", "Healthy", "UAT",
    "company2", "Healthy", "UAT", 
    "company4", "Healthy", "UAT",
    "company5", "Healthy", "UAT",
];
union table1, table2, table3
| summarize by companyCode
| join kind=leftouter ( table1 | extend DEV = status) on companyCode
| join kind=leftouter ( table2 | extend TEST = status) on companyCode
| join kind=leftouter ( table3 | extend UAT = status) on companyCode
| project companyCode, DEV, TEST, UAT
```

| companyCode | DEV | TEST | UAT |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| company1 | Healthy | Healthy | Healthy |
| company2 | Healthy | Healthy | Healthy |
| company3 | Healthy |  |  |
| company4 |  | Healthy | Healthy |
| company5 |  |  | Healthy |

Comment: Yes, it's working. You saved my day. Thanks a lot.